# PySpark UDF, only None values at the input

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, cloudera

I have trouble with UDF function at my Kafka streaming application. Everytime when UDF function is called only None value is on the input instead of valid column value. TypeError 
then raised, because app expecting str, not None.

UDF function definition:

```py
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def get_asn(ip_addr):
    from fm_kafka2parquet.asn_lookup import AsnLookup

    result = AsnLookup\
        .get_instance(ASN_DB_PATH)\
        .get().lookup(ip_addr)[0]  # first record from tuple is ASN number
    if result is None:
        return "n/a"
    return result
```

UDF function calling:

```
  # data frame for netflow reading
  df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", CONFIG_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP) \
      .option("subscribe", CONFIG_KAFKA_TOPIC) \
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
      .load() \
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
      .withColumn("net", from_json("value", Structures.get_ipfix_structure())) \
      .select("net.*")

  # remove ipfix prefix in case of ipfixv1 collector
  temp_list = []
  for c in df.columns:
      new_name = c.replace('ipfix.', '')
      temp_list.append(new_name)
  df = df.toDF(*temp_list)

  # enrichment
  edf = df \
      .withColumn("sourceAS", get_asn('sourceIPv4Address')) \
      .withColumn("destinationAS", get_asn('destinationIPv4Address'))
```

Everything ends with err, which is raised by pyasn library used by get_asn UDF function:

```
TypeError: search_best() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like mentioned below.
.withColumn("sourceAS", get_asn(F.col('sourceIPv4Address'))

Comment: Hi Prateek, if you mean **import pyspark.sql.functions as F** ... **.withColumn("sourceAS", get_asn(F.col('sourceIPv4Address')))**. I tried it but without success, still only None at the UDF function input

Answer (score 0):

Also, this looks fishy.

```
# remove ipfix prefix in case of ipfixv1 collector
  temp_list = []
  for c in df.columns:
      new_name = c.replace('ipfix.', '')
      temp_list.append(new_name)
  df = df.toDF(*temp_list)
```

You're making changes in the column names and then selecting them, but the new column names are not in the dataframe right? So, it must be returning empty dataframe.

If you want to rename the columns use -

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace('ipfix.', ''))
```

For details on how to clean column names in pyspark refer to this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAHPAP9Oagc&t=1s

Comment: I tried it also with **df.withColumnRenamed** - without success. Now I am suspecting the Cloudera platform because everything works fine at my local environment.